# Normalisation of product/protocol review system

Tags: mysql, normalization, rating, review

I'm working on a review system, where reviews for products are shown based on the outcome of a questionnaire.

Example:

1. What food do you like (Italian, French or fusion)
2. Which vegetables do you like (spinach, tomato or broccoli)
3. How much money would you like to spend on dinner ($0-$10, $11-$20 or $21-$30)

If someone selects Italian, tomato, $0-$10, then the user would see (for example) 20 types of pizza's, with reviews from other users shown.
But we only want to show products that have been reviewed for the exact same outcome of the questionnaire (we call this the protocol).

```
Table: questions
-----------------------------------
| id | question                   |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | What food do you like      |
-----------------------------------
| 2  | Which vegetables do you... |
-----------------------------------

Table: possible_answers
-----------------------------------
| id | question_id | answer       |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 1           | Italian      |
-----------------------------------
| 2  | 1           | French       |
-----------------------------------

Table: products
---------------------
| id | product      |
---------------------
| 1  | Pizza Salami | 
---------------------
| 2  | Pizza cheese | 
---------------------
```

From a database perspective (we're using mySQL), I'm wondering how to store the protocol attached to each review

```
[OPTION 1]
Table: reviews
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | product_id   | answer_q1_id | answer_q2_id | answer_q3_id | rating |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2            | 3            | 57           | 166          | 4      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 25           | 3            | 57           | 166          | 5      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[/OPTION 1]


[OPTION 2]
Table: reviews
-------------------------------
| id | product_id   | rating |
-------------------------------
| 1  | 2            | 4       |
-------------------------------
| 2  | 25           | 5       |
-------------------------------

Table: protocol
-----------------------------------------------
| id | review_id    | question_id | answer_id |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1            | 1           | 3         |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1            | 2           | 57        |
-----------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1            | 3           | 166       |
-----------------------------------------------
[/OPTION 2]
```

Normally, I'd go with option 2 which just 'feels' better. But I'm not sure how one could query the protocol table to get all product reviews for a specific path in the questionnaire (protocol). For example when the user answers 'italian, spinach, 0-10', how do I find out which product reviews go with that combination of answers using option 2 (with option 1 it is obvious how to do this)?

I hope I've explained this well and I'm looking forward to reading thoughts from the community.

Greatly appreciated,

Lionel.